# Should I keep DB migration scripts generated via alembic under version control

Tags: git, sqlalchemy, database-migration, alembic

I am using SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL on my live site. For database migrations, I am using alembic. I have some questions regarding the best strategy to do this .

1. Do I need to keep my DB migration scripts under version control?
2. I use Fabric for automated deployments. Should I run migration scripts by hand or I can make it automated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you ever expect to use your DB migration scripts again -- yes, keep them under version control. (It sometimes helps with debugging/forensics too.)

Comment: Even if they are generated? Shouldn't he just version the sources that allow to generate those scripts?

Comment: @mgarciaisaia The scripts may be generated but you should always go over them to check for possible problems. There may be some dialect-specific things that alembic doesn't know how to work with, e.g., creating PostgreSQL index using the function `to_tsvector`. You should always keep them in the source control so you don't need to do these additional manual changes again. It's also better for automation (CI/CD pipelines). You can get rid of the version files once you don't need them (i.e., all DBs are running later versions and you're sure you don't need to downgrade).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Mark on version control: there's no reason not to include your migration scripts.

As for Fabric, I prefer to keep migrations out of it, or at least in a task that is not called implicitly by other tasks. That way errors can't be missed.